# Must specify table name for nested table column or attribute

Tags: oracle, plsql, types

I am trying to create a table in PL/SQL Developer and I am getting this error:

> ORA-22913: must specify table name for nested table column or
>   attribute

Here are all the types and tables I have created so far:

```
create or replace type t_bank_information as object(
  sifra_banke           VARCHAR2(20),
  sifra_agencije        VARCHAR2(20),
  sifra_poslovalnice    VARCHAR2(20),
  geslo                 VARCHAR2(20),
  sifra_delovnega_mesta VARCHAR2(20),

  constructor function t_bank_information (self in out nocopy t_bank_information) return self as result
);
/

create or replace type t_credentials as object(
  ime                   VARCHAR2(20),
  priimek               VARCHAR2(20),
  naslov                VARCHAR2(20),
  vrstaOD               VARCHAR2(20),
  stOD                  VARCHAR2(20),

  constructor function t_credentials(self in out nocopy t_credentials) return self as result
);
/

create or replace type t_order as object(
  vodilni_slog          VARCHAR2(20),
  iban_placnka          VARCHAR2(20),
  polog                 VARCHAR2(20),
  referenca_placnika    VARCHAR2(20),
  ime                   VARCHAR2(20),
  ulica_placnika        VARCHAR2(20),
  kraj_placnika         VARCHAR2(20),
  znesek                NUMBER,
  datum                 VARCHAR2(20),
  nujno                 VARCHAR2(20),
  koda_namena           VARCHAR2(20),
  namen_placila         VARCHAR2(20),
  rok_placila           VARCHAR2(20),
  iban_prejemnika       VARCHAR2(20),
  referenca_prejemnika  VARCHAR2(20),
  ime_prejemnika        VARCHAR2(20),
  ulica_prejemnika      VARCHAR2(20),
  kraj_prejemnika       VARCHAR2(20),
  vsota_dolzin_polj     VARCHAR2(20),
  rezerva               VARCHAR2(20),
  celota                BLOB,

  constructor function t_order(self in out nocopy t_order) return self as result
);
/

create or replace type t_order_arr as table of t_order;
/

create or replace type t_postRequest as object(
  orders            t_order_arr,
  credentials       t_credentials,
  bankInformation   t_bank_information,

  constructor function t_postRequest(self in out nocopy t_postRequest) return self as result
);
/
```

I get error when I finally want to run this command:

> `create table tab_POST_data of t_postRequest;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The orders column is a nested table type. So you need to specify the properties for this in the `nested table` clause

```
create table tab_POST_data 
  of t_postRequest
  nested table orders 
    store as orders_tab;
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick response! I tryed:
create table tab_POST_data(
  orders  t_order_arr,
  credentials    t_credentials,
  bankInformation t_bank_information
)
NESTED TABLE orders STORE AS orders_nt;

But then I had trouble inserting into table! Your answer was very helpful.

Comment: Cheers; raise a new question if you're struggling with the inserts!

Comment: No, the insert works as it should when creating the table the way you showed me :)